# Decomposition of a proper morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hello,

Does any proper morphism $X \to Y$ of, say, algebraic varieties, can be factored as $X \to Z \times Y \to Y$, where $X \to Z \times Y$ is a closed embedding, and $Z \times Y \to Y$ is the projection (and $Z$ is complete).

I ask just out of curiosity.

Sasha

Comment: You can just set $Z = X$, and the closed embedding is given by the graph morphism $\Gamma_f = (id, f)$.

Comment: @ABayer: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1392

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Nagata's theorem there is an open immersion $j:X\hookrightarrow \overline{X}$ where $\overline{X}$ is complete. Then, as ABayer suggests, take $(j,f): \overline{X}\times Y$.

Comment: @Laurent:  What if X is nonseparated?  Perhaps your definition of "algebraic variety" includes separated.

Comment: I am confused -- it seems to me that $(j,f)$ has no reason to be a closed immersion.

Comment: @Dan: Maybe I am wrong, but I think that: Any morphism having a left inverse is a closed embedding, since it is a base change of diagonal (I assume for simplicity that everything is separated). Then our $X \to Xbar \times Y$ is a locally closed embedding, since it is a composition of the closed embedding $X \to X \times Y$ (it has left inverse) with the open embedding $X \times Y \to Xbar \times Y$. On the other hand, $X \to Xbar \times Y$ is proper, since it is the composition $X \to Xbar \times X \to Xbar \times Y$, first arrow being a closed embedding, and second being proper.

Comment: @Jason: you are right, I should have assumed separatedness. Otherwise, I don't know the answer.